# Getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin error even tho i added app.useCors (Angular, c# .net core API)

Tags: c#, .net, angular, api, asp.net-core-webapi

Still getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin error even tho i added useCors in my startup class. I am also using angular 5. I used to get this error when I ran my project but i fixed it by adding cors in my startup, but now i am getting it when i try to call post api method from my angular project.
[image: Error that I get in chrome]

my startup.cs code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;

    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();

        services.AddMvc();

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials());

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();

    }

}
```

Comment: Check this out with MVC. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1#globally

Comment: Im using API .net core

Comment: Then why did you add MVC into it @Aleksandar ?

Comment: can you reach to you'r api action via postman ? if you can't the problem is from you'r mvc routing and you should paste more codes in you'r question , by the way I post a trick ( proxy ) in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use proxy in your client and change client's origin to whatever you want.

**The advantages of this solution are :**

1. You don't need to define CORS in you'r back-end ( increase security )
2. You don't need to be worry about your client as well as you just run your project via **npm start**, as soon as you want to release your application you can run **ng build** command and proxy will be ignored from your setting.

For using proxy

1. edit `"start"` of your `package.json` to look below

   `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",`
2. create a new file called `proxy.conf.json` in the root of the project and inside of that define your proxies like below

   ```
   {
     "/api/*": {
       "target": "http://localhost:56492",
       "secure": "false"
     }
   }
   ```
3. Important thing is that you use `npm start` instead of `ng serve`

Now in you'r service.ts , post/get requests url instead of localhost:56492/... just type /api/Film.

Read more from here : [Proxy Setup angular 2 cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

Comment: Should I make proxy.conf.json in wwwroot in c# api or in angular?

Comment: Create it in the directory which **package.json** is

Comment: my api's url is http://localhost:56492 and angular project's http://localhost:4200, now i got this error  http://localhost:4200/api/Film 404 (Not Found) and the HttpErrorResponse error that i got before.

Comment: change **"/api": {** to **"/api/*": {** and test , I edited my post

Comment: Still getting http://localhost:4200/api/Film 404 (Not Found) and HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/Film", ok: false, …}

Comment: Are you sure that you are compiling your code with npm start ? dont use ng serve , if you are sure about it , share you'r code in stackblitz or github ...

Comment: I forget to add 2 things , 1. instead of  "secure": false , write "secure": "false" 2. in you'r service instead of api/Film write /api/Film . I test it with you'r core and it works. If you want i can push correct core into your repository in GitHub

Comment: I changed it and now i get this error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: That means your client and proxy are  working fine the problem is client can't find you'r api ( controller/action ) . please vote up the answer and upload you'r api source, i will check it by today.

Comment: I fixed it by adding [FromBody] in my api's post method before parameter